# Hyperledger - Explorer : Not all peers are shown in explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I have successfully set up and run my 3 orderers, 3 orgs - 9 peers hyperledger fabric network. Although hyperledger explorer seems to be running in the standardized way (no docker)  without error, it only shows peers specified in CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT protocol of organization "org1MSP", found in line 10 of config.json file.

Please find below the config.json file.

```
{
"name": "test-network",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"client": {
    "tlsEnable": true,
    "adminUser": "admin",
    "adminPassword": "adminpw",
    "enableAuthentication": false,
    "organization": "org1MSP",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "mychannel": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer1.test.com",
            "orderer2.test.com",
            "orderer2.test.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.test.com": {},
            "peer1.org1.test.com": {},
            "peer2.org1.test.com": {},
            "peer0.org2.test.com": {},
            "peer1.org2.test.com": {},
            "peer2.org2.test.com": {},
            "peer0.org3.test.com": {},
            "peer1.org3.test.com": {},
            "peer2.org3.test.com": {}
        },
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "6000",
                    "eventHub": "6000",
                    "eventReg": "6000"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "org1MSP": {
        "mspid": "org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.test.com",
            "peer1.org1.test.com",
            "peer2.org1.test.com"
        ],
        "fullpath": true,
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/users/Admin@org1.test.com/msp/keystore/7f7056172b7d3667783dfa1567e8a8617512ded3e7ace54d04ce49e4d66882f1_sk"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/users/Admin@org1.test.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.test.com-cert.pem"
        }
    },
    "org2MSP": {
        "mspid": "org2MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org2.test.com",
            "peer1.org2.test.com",
            "peer2.org2.test.com"
        ],
        "fullpath": true,
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.test.com/users/Admin@org2.test.com/msp/keystore/9b1c877670442b629bc2512f96f2b4e5f534cbe97c47657dcfcfa3e3a1d13a5f_sk"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.test.com/users/Admin@org2.test.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.test.com-cert.pem"
        }
    },
    "org3MSP": {
        "mspid": "org3MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org3.test.com",
            "peer1.org3.test.com",
            "peer2.org3.test.com"
        ],
        "fullpath": true,
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.test.com/users/Admin@org3.test.com/msp/keystore/a1d310fc74eea57d6242dcbeced092e8c89076683f4b83266d51264a8121ab5c_sk"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.test.com/users/Admin@org3.test.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org3.test.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.test.com": {
        "name": "org1",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer0.org1.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer1.org1.test.com": {
        "name": "org1",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer1.org1.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:8053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer2.org1.test.com": {
        "name": "org1",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.test.com/peers/peer2.org1.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:9053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer2.org1.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer0.org2.test.com": {
        "name": "org2",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.test.com/peers/peer0.org2.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:10053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer1.org2.test.com": {
        "name": "org2",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.test.com/peers/peer1.org2.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:11051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:11053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org2.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer2.org2.test.com": {
        "name": "org2",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.test.com/peers/peer2.org2.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:12051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:12053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer2.org2.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer0.org3.test.com": {
        "name": "org3",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.test.com/peers/peer0.org3.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:13051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:13053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org3.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer1.org3.test.com": {
        "name": "org3",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.test.com/peers/peer1.org3.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:14051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:14053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org3.test.com"
        }
    },
    "peer2.org3.test.com": {
        "name": "org3",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/xarhs/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.test.com/peers/peer2.org3.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:15051",
        "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:15053",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer2.org3.test.com"
        },
        "orderers": {
            "orderer1.test.com": {
                "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050"
            },
            "orderer2.test.com": {
                "url": "grpcs://localhost:8050"
            },
            "orderer3.test.com": {
                "url": "grpcs://localhost:9050"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have tried changing org1MSP to org2MSP etc. and explorer successfully show only relevant peers. I am having a hard time trying to figure out why explorer can not parse successfully all orgs.
Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: you need CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT in all the peers that you want to see in explorer.

Comment: i have added one peer of each org in another peer's CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT so that all peers are connected. Do you mean that i should highlight multiple peers in a single one's CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT ?

Comment: After studying a bit more about CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT, i found that i had added wrong peer information in each peer's CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @StamGR is your problem solved? did you tried in multi-node ?

Comment: @sharif2008 i rewrote the correct CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT values in each peer and explorer did successfully identified blockchain network